# Creating a gui element in java

Tags: java, swing

When you create a GUI element such as a JFrame like this

```
new JFrame(); // nothing pointing to it.
```

is this wrong because there is nothing pointing to it, so it will be garbage collected.  I realize this works, but I want to make sure this works all the time, even if the garbage collector runs.

Comment: JFrame missed method finalize(), then never will be GC'ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to save a reference variable that refers to the `JFrame` object (unless you want to use it later). All you need is to call the constructor `JFrame()`, and the window will be constructed. Hence, in all cases, it should work without any problem.

Comment: Does it create an internal reference somewhere?

Comment: Can you provide some more info? Why doesnt the collector grab it? From my understanding anything lacking a referring pointer in the current execution stack will be lost..